# Multiple instances of Jquery dropdown not working together

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I found the following code in another thread here to create a Jquery dropdown menu:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.statecontent').hide();
   $('#' + $('#myselector').val()).show();
   $('#myselector').change(function(){
      $('.statecontent').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).val()).show();    
   });
});
```

HTML would look like this

```html
<select id="myselector">
   <option value="state1">State 1</option>
   <option value="state2">State 2 </option>
   <option value="state3">State 3</option>
</select>

<div id="state1" class="statecontent">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state2" class="statecontent">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state3" class="statecontent">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
```

This works just fine except for one problem: when I use multiple instances of the dropdown on the same page, it only runs the first dropdown correct, the content for the other dropdowns is not shown and only the dropdown box is shown. I actually want to use 3 dropdowns on the same page. Does anybody have an idea what's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you use unique id's for your dropdowns?

Comment: are you trying this? http://jsfiddle.net/rLjdpz8q/

Comment: @Mackan I would bet that that is exactly the issue.  

You need to use unique ID's for each dropdown, and you will need to adjust your js accordingly.

Comment: @Sushil You have provided a common content area for all 3 dropdowns, but I want 3 separate content areas for 3 separate dropdowns.

Comment: oh. i thought u just needed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id attribute has to be unique. Using the same "instance" (as you put it) of the dropdown several times suggest that you use the same Id. But if you just change your Id's, your jQuery would no longer function as it's currently written.

I would suggest you use class as selector for the dropdowns instead. Also if you want them in different content areas, perhaps store a class selector for those in a data attribute, or wrap it in a new div:

```
<select id="myselector1" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent1">
<select id="myselector2" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent2">
<select id="myselector3" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent3">
```

Then change the jQuery to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myselector').each(function(i, elem) {
    $('.' + $(this).data('class')).hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
  $('.myselector').change(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).data('class')).hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

A working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('.statecontent1').hide();
  $('.myselector').each(function(i, elem) {
    $('.' + $(this).data('class')).hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
  $('.myselector').change(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).data('class')).hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselector1" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent1">
  <option value="state1">State 1</option>
  <option value="state2">State 2</option>
  <option value="state3">State 3</option>
</select>
<div id="state1" class="statecontent1">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state2" class="statecontent1">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state3" class="statecontent1">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<select id="myselector2" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent2">
  <option value="state4">State 4</option>
  <option value="state5">State 5</option>
  <option value="state6">State 6</option>
</select>
<div id="state4" class="statecontent2">State4 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state5" class="statecontent2">State5 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state6" class="statecontent2">State6 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<select id="myselector3" class="myselector" data-class="statecontent3">
  <option value="state7">State 7</option>
  <option value="state8">State 8</option>
  <option value="state9">State 9</option>
</select>
<div id="state7" class="statecontent3">State7 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state8" class="statecontent3">State8 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
<div id="state9" class="statecontent3">State9 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
```

Comment: You have provided a common content area for all 3 dropdowns, but I want 3 separate content areas for 3 separate dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each one in a div, so you can traverse the jquery modules easily:

```js
$('.statecontent').hide();
$('.myselector').parent().find('#' + $('.myselector').val()).show();
$('.myselector').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.statecontent').hide();
  $(this).parent().find('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="myselector">
    <option value="state1">State 1</option>
    <option value="state2">State 2</option>
    <option value="state3">State 3</option>
  </select>
  <div id="state1" class="statecontent">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
  <div id="state2" class="statecontent">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
  <div id="state3" class="statecontent">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <select class="myselector">
    <option value="state1">State 1</option>
    <option value="state2">State 2</option>
    <option value="state3">State 3</option>
  </select>
  <div id="state1" class="statecontent">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
  <div id="state2" class="statecontent">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
  <div id="state3" class="statecontent">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div>
</div>
```